# Unity c# Flick object to direction regardless of camera angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, swipe

I have this following particular code to flick an object forward by swiping in the direction that i want. The issue is that my camera angle is rotated so whenever i flick the object to the center or left, the flick isnt accurate. When i flick anywhere to the right, the object is thrown precisely. How can i adjust this code so that the object is throw to the world space direction regardless of camera rotation please. Thanks.

Code:`public class SwipeScript : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public float force = 2f;
public bool isTarget = false;
public float zFactor = 2f;

public Vector3 startPosition;

private Vector2 startSwipe;
private Vector2 endSwipe;
private Rigidbody currentBoxRb;

void Start()
{
    currentBoxRb = StackerManager.currentBox.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    startPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        startSwipe = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {

        endSwipe = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (isTarget == true)
        {
            Swipe();
            isTarget = false;

        }


    }
}
void Swipe()
{
    Vector3 swipe = endSwipe - startSwipe;
    swipe.z = swipe.y / zFactor;
    swipe.y = -0.001f;
    currentBoxRb.isKinematic = false;
    currentBoxRb.AddForce(swipe * force, ForceMode.Impulse);

}

private void OnMouseDown()
{

    currentBoxRb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
    isTarget = true;

}
```

}

Comment: To clarify, do you want it to always go in the direction of the flick, even if the camera is rotated?

Comment: Yes, but im worried as the gameobject itself is already rotated by 23degrees on the Y each time its instantiated. I want it to flick exactly where im pointing regardless of all rotations :/